# Suffering to receive the CDI contract from a Business company

Tags: new-job, contracts, employer, employees, signatures

I have been accepted in a business company to sign with them my first CDI employment (permanent employee contract). My question is how long it takes for the company's president to prepare the contract for the employee? I am waiting since one month and the president still didn't send me the CDI contract for the signature. At each time I contact the company's president, he says to me that he is still preparing the contract. Is this normal?

Any help or suggestions will be very appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, it should not take a company 1 month to prepare any contract. Perhaps, you should continue your job search with other companies. Good luck.

Comment: I assume you've already accepted their offer, that's why they're taking so long to prepare the contract. Right now, since they have you on the backburner, may be they're trying to see if they can hire someone better or someone cheaper than you. You need to keep on looking for another employer. Stop being someone's plan B.

Comment: @Stephan yes I accepted their offer and they also sent to me a message confirmation that they want to hire me. But they already confirmed to me, so can they still hire someone else? This will be hypocrite if they do that!!!

Comment: @Job_September unfortunately it is too late for me, I have been in contact with the company two months and they already sent to me a message confirmation for hiring. So I don't really know what is the probability that they are lying or still trying to see other candidates...

Comment: @Christina, Yes, it's too late, but it's not like you have a choice right now. Restart your job search now! The longer you wait, the worse it's going to be. If this job does come through anyway, that's great! No harm, no foul. But in case it doesn't come through, you need a contingency plan, even if that contingency plan means that you will still be unemployed for the next three months. After all, being unemployed for the next three months is better than being unemployed for the next six months.

Comment: @Christina, Yes, employers can be hypocrites. That's life. The next time you're asked if you accept their offer, say "This looks good. Send me the contract. I'll make my decision then" (or say something to that effect). When you say this, I can guarantee you that they'll stop everything else they're doing and overnight you the contract as soon as they can. This also lessens the likelihood that they'll omit anything from the contract that they promised you during the interview. And whatever you do, never pause your job search until you've signed the full contract and have a firm starting date.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thank you for all your suggestions. I appreciate a lot. I will search another job right now but hope the employers I contacted are not hypocrite and that they send me the contract very soon. My fault is that I saw them that I am very interested to the job offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this normal?

It does happen, especially if there are multiple steps and reviews in preparing a contract (HR, finance, legal, department, background check, etc.).

Whether it's "normal" or not depends a lot on context: country, culture, size, type of business. For a government-type employer in a paper-work heavy country things will take a lot longer than in a high tech startup in the US.

As long as you still get answers on your follow ups, things are probably still ok. Nevertheless: it's typically best practice to continue your job search until you have a written offer or contract in hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)) do you think that a company can lie even if they sent to me a message confirmation that they want yo hire me? Do you think that I may still be in the plan B after this confirmation?

Comment: Sure, a company can lie,. If that's the case, you really don't want to work there anyway.

Comment: @Himar I will see with them this week, if I don't receive the contract, in this case I think they are lying on me.